# ElmahR does not catch any exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmahr

I'm trying to install ElmahR on my existing MVC5 project. Before installed ElmahR, I'm using Elmah and NLog to handle the exception. Based on this [tutorial](http://gregorsuttie.com/2013/04/03/elmahr-monitor-errors-in-your-app-using-a-dashboard/) I installed the ElmahR using nuget package

```
Install-Package ElmahR.Elmah
```

Then in the web.config, I changed this line:

```
<errorPost targetUrl="http://TARGET_DASHBOARD_URL" sourceId="SOURCE_IDENTIFIER_URI_AS_LISTED_IN_DASHBOARD_CONFIG" secret="SECRET_PASSPHRASE_(SPECIFY_JUST_IN_CASE_OF_ENCRYPTED_POST)" />
```

into

```
<errorPost targetUrl="http://localhost:62335/posterror.axd" sourceId="MyCode" />
```

Next step I installed the Dashboard

```
Install-Package ElmahR.Modules.Dashboard
```

and changed this line:

```
<application name="Sample application" sourceId="SomeCode" infoUrl="http://localhost:12345/elmah.axd" testExceptionUrl="http://localhost:12345/elmah.axd/test" />
```

into

```
<application name="WPS" sourceId="MyCode" infoUrl="http://localhost:62335/elmah.axd" testExceptionUrl="http://localhost:62335/elmah.axd/test" />
```

In HomeController (Index) I generate error by `throw new exception("Test ElmahR");` and Run. Then I go to `http://locahost:62335/elmahr/dashboard` and see no exception catched, but if I see `http://localhost:62335/elmah` it catched error "Path '/posterror.axd' was not found" not Test ElmahR. Why?

Full web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorPost" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="elmahr" type="ElmahR.Core.Config.SectionHandler, ElmahR.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="WPSWorklog" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorPost" type="ElmahR.Elmah.ErrorPostModule, ElmahR.Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorPost" type="ElmahR.Elmah.ErrorPostModule, ElmahR.Elmah" />
      <!--
        You may want to enable the following declaration in order 
        to have your dashboard collecting errors happening inside 
        the dashboard itself (ELMAH is needed and must be properly 
        configured).
        -->
      <!--<add name="ErrorPost" type="ElmahR.Core.ErrorTrapModule, ElmahR.Core" />-->
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="PostError" verb="POST" path="PostError.axd" type="ElmahR.Core.PostError, ElmahR.Core" />
      <add name="YSOD" verb="GET,HEAD" path="YellowScreenOfDeath.axd" type="ElmahR.Core.YellowScreenOfDeath, ElmahR.Core" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WPSWorklogEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.WPSWorklog.csdl|res://*/Models.WPSWorklog.ssdl|res://*/Models.WPSWorklog.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=WPSWorklog;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
    <!--<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/XMLLog" />-->
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <and>
          <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
          <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" pattern="/favicon\.ico(\z|\?)" />
        </and>
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.MemoryErrorLog, Elmah" />
    <errorPost targetUrl="http://localhost:62335/posterror.axd" sourceId="MyCode" />
  </elmah>
  <elmahr>
    <application name="WPS" sourceId="MyCode" infoUrl="http://localhost:62335/elmah.axd" testExceptionUrl="http://localhost:62335/elmah.axd/test" />
  </elmahr>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE 1

As @Wasp suggestion, I register the Elmah Modules and Handlers in `system.web` AND `system.webServer` but still not solved the problem:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  ...
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  ...
  <handlers>
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </handlers>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: What server are you using? IIS or Web Dev server from VS?

Comment: @Wasp sorry for late reply, I don't know whether it runs using IIS or Web Dev server from VS. How to know that? I installed ElmahR on existing MVC5 which is created using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web - New Project - ASP.NET Web Application - MVC.

Comment: You can check the Properties of your Project, under the Web tab

Comment: @Wasp I'm using IIS Express

Comment: ok, so this is weird, it should work as easily as it did for you with VS2012, unless MVC5 in particular requires some special handling to declare the handler, I never really tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT using IIS (Full or Express), you might have the issue because I do not see the `system.web/httpHandlers` section in your `web.config`, which is where you would declare the missing `posterror.axd` endpoint. The endpoint is there in the `system.webserver/handlers` section, but that requires IIS. Did you check that?

Comment: Hm..I'm not sure how to check that? As a comparison, I create a new MVC4 Project in VS 2012 Express and do the same way, and when I see the dashboard the error is shown. There is no system.web/httpHandlers in the web.config, but it catches the exception. Is there any compatibility problem with VS Express 2013 for Web?

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular compatibility issue, but I'm not sure what happens with those specific scenarios and whether they use IIS or not. Maybe try to add `system.web/httpHandlers` in the VS 2013 project and check if it helps. You shold be able to figure out how to setup that handler by checking some docs around and transposing what you have in `system.webserver/handlers`